# Send form with input type="radio"

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, send, phpmailer

I need to send form answers through PHPMailer, but I can receive only textarea fields. Options with radio buttons sending error messages:

```
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Message body empty
```

I have defined value, eg:  `<input type="radio" name="question1" value="value1">value1`

...I need to receive "value1" in my e-mail.

php:

```
$ot1 = $_POST['question1'];
$mail->Body = $ot1;
```

Comment: What do you get at `$ot1` variable ?

Comment: Shomz still error message

Comment: Subir Kumar Sao 1 it's because I want simplier body of email, I need question1 received as value1 in email, I need simple email with "value1" nothing more...

Comment: No, don't try to send it like that, just paste the var_dump output here.

Answer (score 0):

To receive information of a radio button, you must select it (checked = "checked"). 
And more, it takes at least two radio buttons, or use a checkbox.

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="value1" checked="checked">value1
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="value2" >value2
```

I hope it will help. :)